# Javawebparts Ajaxparts: Using same Axis event multiple times in signle form

Tags: ajax, web-parts

I'm using Javawebparts Ajaxparts and would like to use one axis event multiple times in a form.

Problem is that std:InnerHTML responseHandler takes its target html tag id in axis-config.xml so it seems impossible to reuse the definition when only thing that should change is the target tag id.

Is there a way to set responseHandler parameters on the the page where it is used (in asix:event tag or someting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by constructing several kludge solutions to work around the many many limitations of Ajaxparts. There probably is a much better ajax framework one could be using instead of JavaWebparts.